# Email starts with non-descript text

Tags: discussion, feature-request

My inbox displays all notification emails from stackoverflow as:

```
Stack Exchange  New xxx question for Mar 2 - Stack Exchange - 
  The following item was added to your Stack Exchange "xxx" feed
```

all in one line, nothing else. This is all boilerplate text, and note the duplication of xxx and the triplication of "Stack Exchange".

The actual newsworthy content of this text is minimal, compared to other automated messages from lists or other services. Even though many SO questions are poorly worded it would help to learn a little about the actual question just by looking at the email in the inbox.

Maybe something can be done about this.

Comment: This should probably be on MetaSE, as it presumably affects all network sites.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is this a meta-meta? If, on stackoverflow, I go to "Ask  Question", I'm told "If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead." And the meta I'm being redirected to is this meta.

Comment: Yes, a "Meta Meta" - as this applies to the whole network, not just SO, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/